# Insert an element at specific place in a list

Tags: python

i have a problem using list.insert method. You can see my code below.

```
z=[1,9,6,5,5,3,4,6]
y=['1','4','9','7','6','5','5','1','5','0','3','3','4','1','6','0']
z.insert(z[0],int(y[1]))
print(z)
[1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6]
z.insert(z[2],int(y[3]))
print(z)
[1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Why does 7 go after 6 and not after 9????
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z=[1,9,6,5,5,3,4,6]
y=['1','4','9','7','6','5','5','1','5','0','3','3','4','1','6','0']
z.insert(z[0],int(y[1]))  #grabs 1 from z, and 4 from y
print(z)
[1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6]
z.insert(z[2],int(y[3]))  #grabs index 2 from z which is 9, 
                          #and insert will insert into the last element 
                          #if the index is out of range
print(z)
[1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: His code doesn't reassign the result, why do you have that last comment in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

`z[2]` is `9`.

```
[1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6]
       ^
```

You move it to the 9th index (after `6`).